# How to search for Text in a ListBox?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

So here's what my program looks

[image: Click this]

What i want to do is search for how many occurrences there are of one grade

Here's the code a friend helped me do

```
Private Function countOccOfMark(ByVal mark As String)
    Dim resultCount As Integer = 0

    For cnt As Integer = 0 To lstDisplay.Items.Count - 1
        Dim gradeMark As String = lstDisplay.Items(cnt)
        Dim results() As String = gradeMark.Split(vbTab)

        For Each res As String In results
            If (res = mark) Then
                resultCount = resultCount + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    Return resultCount
End Function


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim mark As String = InputBox("Enter a Grade to search for")
    Dim amountFound As Integer = countOccOfMark(mark)
    MessageBox.Show("Found " & amountFound & " Occurences of the mark " & mark)
End Sub
```

Which works fine but I'm sure there's a easier way to do it

Comment: A) A listview would allow you to display the contents in proper columns so that you do not need to split the data to examine it. 2) A Class which holds the Name, Grade Percent could be displayed as shown (using `ToString()` but keep the data separately so you do not need to split the data to examine it

Answer (score 1):

The inner `For-Next` is unnecessary. The grade is always in the second column.

```
Private Function countOccOfMark(ByVal mark As String)
    Dim resultCount As Integer = 0

    For cnt As Integer = 0 To lstDisplay.Items.Count - 1
        Dim gradeMark As String = lstDisplay.Items(cnt)
        Dim results() As String = gradeMark.Split(vbTab)
        If results(1) = mark Then
            resultCount = resultCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    Return resultCount
End Function
```

Comment: I knew there was another way to do it! Thanks man you're a great help

Comment: @Thomas06501 You're welcome. If this works, please accept my response as "answered"--unless you what to try to keep the conversation open.